# Excel - search for specific text in a row then copy and paste that value into a specific cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to search each row of a spreadsheet for a mac address with format `**:**:**:**:**:**`

I want to search cells h3-z3 for a mac address and when found copy and paste the mac address into g3

Once I have the formula for one row I will fill down for all rows of the spreadsheet

Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your title says Excel so I assumed that is what you wanted and removed the other tags.  If you wanted google sheets please [edit] the question to indicate that and remove the references to Excel.

Comment: Will that format only be in one cell in each row?  If not how do you want the output?

Comment: @ScottCraner Yes- that format will be only in one cell in each row

Comment: Thank you @ScottCraner! That solved it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use INDEX/MATCH with wildcards:

```
=INDEX(H3:Z3,MATCH("*:*:*:*:*:*",H3:Z3,0))
```